# Function strcpy() changes value of integer array?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, strcpy

I'll start off with the code I have currently where *input* is a user provided variable:

```
int current[2] = {-1, -1}, next[2] = {-1, -1};
char *strtok_result = strtok(input, " ");
int i = 0;
while(strtok_result != NULL){
    i++;
    int count = 0;
    char strtok_buffer[2];
    printf("iteration %d-%d: next[0] = %d\n", i, ++count, next[0]);
    strcpy(strtok_buffer, strtok_result);
    printf("iteration %d-%d: next[0] = %d\n", i, ++count, next[0]);

    current[0] = next[0];
    current[1] = next[1];
    next[0] = strtok_buffer[1] - 48;            // ascii conversion, digit to column
    next[1] = toupper(strtok_buffer[0]) - 64;   // --- || ---, letter to row
    printf("iteration %d-%d: next[0] = %d\n\n", i, ++count, next[0]);
    strtok_result = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
return 0;
```

If I enter "A1 B2 C3" I expect the following output:

```
iteration 1-1: next[0] = -1
iteration 1-2: next[0] = -1
iteration 1-3: next[0] = 1

iteration 2-1: next[0] = 1
iteration 2-2: next[0] = 1
iteration 2-3: next[0] = 2

iteration 3-1: next[0] = 2
iteration 3-2: next[0] = 2
iteration 3-3: next[0] = 3
```

The output I receive however looks like the following:

```
iteration 1-1: next[0] = -1
iteration 1-2: next[0] = -256
iteration 1-3: next[0] = 1

iteration 2-1: next[0] = 1
iteration 2-2: next[0] = 0
iteration 2-3: next[0] = 2

iteration 3-1: next[0] = 2
iteration 3-2: next[0] = 0
iteration 3-3: next[0] = 3
```

It seems to me that somehow, during the execution of *strcpy(strtok_buffer, strtok_result);* the value of next[0] is altered. This boggles me. I have encountered similar results before, and that had to do with memory overlapping (term?), but I cannot see why this would occur here.

Any help is appreciated, I have stared myself blind trying to figure this out.

Notes:

- The input has been confirmed to be in a "XY XY ... " format where X is an alpha and Y is a digit.
- current[0], current[1] and next[1] are not altered in any way. I decided to exclude those outputs so you didn't have to look at 2x36 lines of numbers.

Comment: `strcpy` copies the string *plus* terminating null. So to copy "A1" you need at least 3 bytes in your `strtok_buffer` buffer, not 2.

Comment: Wow, I should take a break.. I just now realized it has to be a size of 3. Tried it, and it worked properly. Well, thanks!

Comment: Look at the assembler code and see where the compiler is putting `next` relative to `strtok_buffer`. "memory overlapping (term?)" -- The term you want is "buffer overflow". Hopefully from this experience you will never be boggled by this again, and will always be wary of strcpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtok_buffer[2]` is not large enough to hold the tokens `"A1"`, `"B2"`, or `"C3"`. Don't forget that strings need space for the terminating null character.